# Unclear result of inequality with absolute value

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I am not understanding those solutions that W. Mathematica gives me about this inequality:

$$\frac{x^2-1}{\vert x+1 \vert} \leq 0 $$

I solved it by hand and I find that the solution is $-1 < x \leq 1$, but Mathematica returns me $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

I cannot consider $x = -1$, because it's not part of the domain of the funciton. It holds in "a limit sense", in my opinion.

I solved it with the absolute value definition, but there is no way I can set $x = -1$ that naively. Even if $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ I cannot just simplify, because I would obtain a different function.

Can someone please clarify this to me?

Comment: You are right: $-1 < x \le 1$ is the solution. CASs aren't always the best at double-checking edge cases like that.

Comment: "there is no way I can set x=−1 that naively." You can still first discuss that $x=-1$ has to be excluded. This can be done naivly. After this, $|x+1|$ is a positive real number, we can multiply up, so that we only discuss $x^2-1\le 0$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you so much, and thank you Dietrich too!